# CSS background and body height 100%

Tags: html, css, background

I am having trouble getting my background image to span the entirety of my content.

I looked at other questions and it seems that I need to set a min-width of 100% on each container... but I tried every combination and it still wasn't working.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">

    <div id="header">
                 header content...             
    </div>
    <div id="content">

        <div id="myAccountArea" class="section">
            accountArea content...
        </div>

        <div id="myPostsArea" class="section">
        postsArea content...
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%
}

body {
    background: red;
}

#container {
    padding-top: 80px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    min-width: 1000px;
}

#content {
    min-width:1000px;
}
```

The problem I am having is that the postsArea content usually spans more than the browser's window, but the background does not.

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

Ok, so I narrowed it down to a reset.css file... Any tips on going about discovering the problem in that file?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a demopage where the problem is visible? I get a feeling that this may be a problem with floated divs, but it's hard to say unless we can see the actual page.

Comment: I think what you're searching for is [overflow fix](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/) or [sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/). Am I right?

Comment: There's not enough information here to *definitively* answer your question. I *could* take a guess, but that seems a bit counterproductive for both of us. Either provide a link to a live page, or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)/[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo.

Comment: I created a JSBin page by copying the exact structure and CSS I have. For some reason it works there, but not in my browser? weird

http://jsbin.com/osimoj/3

Comment: Maybe because I am missing the reset stylesheet?

Comment: If you can't figure out how to reproduce the problem, then you'll have to provide a link to your actual page.

Comment: I discovered that a reset stylesheet was causing the problem... see above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so after looking at the reset stylesheet, I discovered this:

```
html {
     background:#FFF
}
```

Commented this line out and everything seems to be fine :)

Thanks a lot for all the help