# can't change body background color using CSS reset

Tags: html, css, yui, css-reset

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hover Zoom</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" >
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS file code (`style.css`):

```
body {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

but the background color of `body` does not change.

Without the CSS reset, it works fine. Can you suggest me a better CSS reset, or any other solution?

Comment: what css reset do you use? Meyer's reset is broadly used

Comment: Does the reset have a background-color attribute?

Comment: @Sotiris, @waitinforatrain: Just visit the link yourselves and see: http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css

Comment: @BoltClock I just focused in the style.css rule and commented. My overlooking

Comment: @BoltClock: `html{background:#FFF;}` [strikes again!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563189/css-background-and-body-height-100/6563353#6563353)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

change your selector to

```
html, body{
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: What YUI actually wants you to do is set the `background` on only `html` - you don't need to also set it on `body`.

Answer (score 6):

brenjt's answer is correct, but I'll provide an explanation for what is wrong and why that solution works:

Your CSS reset file sets the background color of `html` which is the entire page. You are only setting the `body`'s background color, but your body is extremely small in height since you have no content. Consequentially, you do not see the body's background color.

Just set both the `html` and `body` in CSS like this:

```
html, body { background-color: #FF0000; }
```

**EDIT:**

Had you not set the `html` background color, then `body`'s background color would represent the whole page. But since you are using an external source's CSS reset, you do not have the option of not setting the `html` properties.

Comment: Your answer isn't fully correct. Setting just the `body` background [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/zvD2U/), provided one isn't set for `html`. The relevant explanation is here: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#special-backgrounds

Comment: @thirtydot: You are correct, I missed that point. I updated my answer accordingly.