# What is the difference between applying css rules to html compared to body?

Tags: html, css

I don't see the difference between:

```
html {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

and

```
body {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Any explanation?

Comment: Related (to the title, anyway): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565942/should-global-css-styles-be-set-on-the-html-element-or-the-body-element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no real difference (if you're just talking about where to apply `background`, otherwise [BoltClock's answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565942/should-global-css-styles-be-set-on-the-html-element-or-the-body-element) is a better fit). `html` is an element, just like `body` is.

Both are valid choices, and both will both work in all common browsers.

The YUI Reset for instance, chooses to set a `background` on the `html` element instead of `body`:
http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset.css

This requires that you set your `background` on `html`, for instance see: [can't change body background color using CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671846/cant-change-body-background-color-using-css-reset)

**See:** http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#special-backgrounds

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the
>   canvas and its background painting area extends to cover the entire
>   canvas, although any images are sized and positioned relative to the
>   root element as if they were painted for that element alone. (In other
>   words, the background positioning area is determined as for the root
>   element.) If the root's ‘background-color’ value is ‘transparent’, the
>   canvas's background color is UA dependent. The root element does not
>   paint this background again, i.e., the used value of its background is
>   transparent.

And:

> For documents whose root element is an HTML HTML element [HTML401] or
>   an XHTML html element [XHTML11]: if the computed value of
>   ‘background-image’ on the root element is ‘none’ and its
>   ‘background-color’ is ‘transparent’, user agents must instead
>   propagate the computed values of the background properties from that
>   element's first HTML BODY or XHTML body child element. The used values
>   of that BODY element's background properties are their initial values,
>   and the propagated values are treated as if they were specified on the
>   root element. It is recommended that authors of HTML documents specify
>   the canvas background for the BODY element rather than the HTML
>   element.

What that wall of text is saying is demonstrated here:

- `background` on just `body`: http://jsfiddle.net/hhtzE/
- `background` on `html` and `body`: http://jsfiddle.net/hhtzE/1/
- `background` only `html`: http://jsfiddle.net/hhtzE/2/

Answer (score 4):

While `body` and `html` can often be treated the same, they are *not* the same thing. The `body` can have margins, padding, and borders, and be moved relative to the `html` element.
I sometimes use body margin and padding to make a white "page" on a light background, and it prints the same as it looks.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbJyE/1/) for a simple example showing the two can have different background colors.

The relevant CSS is as I commented in nomulous' answer:

```
html {
    background-color: #ffffc0;
}
body {
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 2em;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

There is also the `:root` element because not all browsers (cough.ie.cough) treat the `html` element as the root of the DOM.

Comment: You can also put margin/padding/border on `html`, if you like. I'm sure you know that, but your second sentence maybe sounds like it's saying you can't do that.

Comment: @thirtydot - yes, good clarification, thanks. I *don't* do that but I *could* do that.

Answer (score 3):

html is the parent of body.  One way to see the difference is to do:

```
html {
    overflow: scroll;
}


body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

You will see that there are two nested sets of scrollbars, one belonging to html and the one inside that belonging to body.

Comment: I believe, i.e. also the height is different (actual browser window height (html) vs. document height(body)). Not sure if that ever plays a role w/o javascript use...

Answer (score 2):

Someone wrote here that  is always 100% height but it is not true!

Try to do (tested on FF4):

```
html{
    background:yellow;
}
body{
    background:red;
    height:100px;
}
```

`<body>` color affects `<html>` color only when `<html>` doesn't have color set. The most annoying thing here is when `<body>` has color and `<html>` don't, some browser versions will have trouble with last direct child block element with margin. Color will be cut after the element and margin will be of `<html>` color. It is always true when `<html>` color is set.

On the other hand, when `<html>` background is set, `<body>` can have for example margins. This is simply mess.

Best practice so far is to apply background color, fonts etc to both. Simply every time you will write:

```
body{}
```

change it to:

```
body,html{}
```

Don't use any CSS box-model properties on `<body>` and `<html>` (or leave it unmodified at all, just to have peace of mind). Create inner element (may be of width 100%) and work with it instead.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't normally be any difference at all, because those elements are both supposed to be taking up the full screen. It's just like having a div inside some other div. But I think it's more correct to style the body tag, because html isn't really part of the layout.

Comment: Give your body some margin and you'll see the difference. `html { background-color: green; }
body { padding: 2em;
    margin: 2em;
    background-color: yellow;
}`