# Full body background with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to work on a new project using Twitter's Bootstrap framework, but I am having an issue. I want a full body background, yet the background seems to be limited to the height of the container div. here is the HTML/CSS code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.3.0/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Bootstrap Issue</title>
        <style>
          body { background: black; }
          .container { background: white; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <h1> Hello, World!</h1>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

How can I get the body to take up the entire screen?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to either add this:

```
html { background: transparent }
```

*Or*, set the "page background" (`background: black`) on `html` instead, which is fine to do.

Why? Inside Bootstrap, there's this:

```
html,body{background-color:#ffffff;}
```

(bear in mind the default `background` value is `transparent`)

For more information on why this matters, see: [What is the difference between applying css rules to html compared to body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739601/what-is-the-difference-between-applying-css-rules-to-html-tag-compared-to-body-ta/6739791#6739791)

Note that this is no longer an issue with Bootstrap 3+.

Comment: Presumably, he's already overriding bootstraps color for the background.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Yes he was, but it wasn't working for him. You're not understanding the problem this question was asking about.

Answer (score 8):

Set the height of html and body to be 100% in the CSS.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Then it should work. The problem is that the height of body is automatically calculated to be the height of the contents, rather than the height of the whole screen.

Comment: This almost works, but if you've got a padding-top:60px (to prevent the navbar from appearing over the container at the top), this creates a 60px extra height at the bottom, which doesn't get the background. How do we do "100%-60px" in css?

Comment: EDIT: This is doable using jQuery - $("body").css("height", ($(window).height()-60)+"px"); Does anyone have a pure-CSS method to achieve this?

Comment: html, body{
        height: 100%; /* MAKES SURE THIS ONE IS FIRST */
        min-height: 100%;
    }

Answer (score 5):

/* here is a pure CSS solution */

```
<style type="text/css">
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      #full-screen-background-image {
        z-index: -999;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 1024px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }

      #wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 800px;
        min-height: 400px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        color: #333;
      }

      a:link, a:visited, a:hover {
        color: #333;
        font-style: italic;
      }

      a.to-top:link,
      a.to-top:visited, 
      a.to-top:hover {
        margin-top: 1000px;
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        font-size: 30px;
      }

    </style>
    <body>
  <img src="/background.jpg" id="full-screen-background-image" /> 
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p>Content goes here...</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
      body { background: url(background.png); }
      .container { background: ; }
</style>
```

this works for a background image if you want it

Answer (score 0):

best solution would be

```
.content{
    background-color:red;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

its automatically take veiwport height(vh) in bootstrap.