# background image for homepage

Tags: css

I am quite new to the css and bootstrap i have searched and tried the `w3c` solution and also the SO but did not work well. Actually i want to have an image as a background on my homepage. on which there would be my content like 3 small buttons/icon in the middle of the page.

I have tried this

```
<div id="homepage">

</div>
```

css:

```
#homepage{
    background: url(../images/homepage.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

but it is not working.

2nd Solution:
Second thing which i tried was to include a `img` tag then add my content and drag to the middle by absolute position which i think is not a good way because responsiveness did not remain there.

Can any one help me in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you double checked the image path,I think the problem is the size of the div.

try giving your div a fixed width and height in order to test if at least this way the image is showing.

```
<div id="homepage" style="width:500px;height:300px">
</div>
```

Then check out how to use the bootstrap [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) in order to make your div as big as you wish.

Comment: is it not possible to automatically it covers the whole page?

Comment: Something similar was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568931/full-body-background-with-twitter-bootstrap#7569745 check it out maybe it will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
#homepage{
    background: url(https://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y558vo9a/

Comment: background-size two time ?

Comment: it works fine but is there any solution that it automatically stretched it self according to image?

Comment: That is possible, but your background image would not respond to different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the background image to be in your index page, there is no need in adding '../' and no need in adding background-size, -repeat when you can actually set your code so;

```
 background: url(images/homepage.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

but if it works for you, you can use it so. And i also noticed, you forgot to close your background-repeat with **';'**