# Applying a background to <html> and/or <body>

Tags: html, css

```js
$("#toggle").click(function(){
    $("html").toggleClass("bg");
});
```

```css
html.bg {
    background: blue;
}

body {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="bg">
<head>
</head>

<body>
    Test
    <br>
    <button id="toggle">Toggle HTML background</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I found that if you apply a CSS background to `body`, it takes up the whole page (no matter what the actual height or width of `body` is).

However, if you apply a CSS background to both `html` and `body`, the background for `body` **does not take up the whole page**.

Is this discrepancy expected behavior?

How would I go about superimposing two fullscreen backgrounds (say, a background color and a semi-transparent image?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between applying css rules to html compared to body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739601/what-is-the-difference-between-applying-css-rules-to-html-compared-to-body)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is [correct behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds).<sup>1</sup> [In standards mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214152/why-does-my-div-height-100-work-only-when-doctype-is-removed/32215263#32215263), `body`, [as well as `html`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599919/why-doesnt-the-html-element-take-up-the-whole-browser-viewport/23599937#23599937), doesn't immediately take up the entire height of the viewport, even though it appears so when you only apply a background to the latter. In fact, the `html` element will take on the background of `body` if you don't give it its own background, and `html` will pass this on to the canvas:

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and its background painting area extends to cover the entire canvas, although any images are sized and positioned relative to the root element as if they were painted for that element alone. (In other words, the background positioning area is determined as for the root element.) If the root's ‘background-color’ value is ‘transparent’, the canvas's background color is UA dependent. The root element does not paint this background again, i.e., the used value of its background is transparent.
>
> For documents whose root element is an HTML `HTML` element or an XHTML `html` element: if the computed value of ‘background-image’ on the root element is ‘none’ and its ‘background-color’ is ‘transparent’, user agents must instead propagate the computed values of the background properties from that element's first HTML `BODY` or XHTML `body` child element. The used values of that `BODY` element's background properties are their initial values, and the propagated values are treated as if they were specified on the root element. It is recommended that authors of HTML documents specify the canvas background for the `BODY` element rather than the `HTML` element.

That said, however, you can superimpose any background image over a background color on a single element (either `html` or `body`), without having to rely on two elements — simply use `background-color` and `background-image` or combine them in the `background` shorthand property:

```css
body {
    background: #ddd url(background.png) center top no-repeat;
}
```

If you wish to combine *two background images*, you need to rely on multiple backgrounds. There are chiefly two days to do this:

- In CSS2, this is where styling both elements comes in handy: simply set a background image to `html` and another image to `body` which you wish to superimpose over the first. To ensure the background image on `body` displays at full viewport height, you need to apply `height` and `min-height` respectively as well:

  ```css
  html {
      height: 100%;
      background: #ddd url(background1.png) repeat;
  }

  body {
      min-height: 100%;
      background: transparent url(background2.png) center top no-repeat;
  }
  ```

  Incidentally, the reason why you have to specify `height` and `min-height` to `html` and `body` respectively is because neither element has any intrinsic height. Both are `height: auto` by default. It is the viewport that has 100% height, so `height: 100%` is taken from the viewport, then applied to `body` as a minimum to allow for scrolling of content.
- In CSS3, the syntax has been extended so you can [declare multiple background values in a single property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering), eliminating the need to apply backgrounds to multiple elements (or adjust `height`/`min-height`):

  ```css
  body {
      background: url(background2.png) center top no-repeat, 
                  #ddd url(background1.png) repeat;
  }
  ```

  The only caveat is that in a single multi-layered background, only the bottommost layer may have a background color. You can see in this example that the `transparent` value is missing from the upper layer.

  And don't worry — the behavior specified above with propagating background values works exactly the same even if you use multi-layered backgrounds.

If you need to support older browsers, though, you'll need to go with the CSS2 method, which is supported all the way back to IE7.

My comments under [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187569/whats-the-difference-between-applying-css-to-html-body-and/7187588#7187588) explain, with an accompanying [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vddbh), how `body` is actually offset from `html` by default margins even though it looks like it's being padded out instead, again owing to this seemingly strange phenomenon.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This may have its roots in setting the HTML `background` and `bgcolor` attributes of `body` causing the background attribute to apply to the entire viewport. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565942/should-global-css-styles-be-set-on-the-html-element-or-the-body-element/4565959#4565959).</sub>

Comment: Can you provide W3C specification reference related to this, so your answer becomes a fact and not a speculation?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Heh, sorry about that. Quick successive edits are how I roll. It should be more complete now.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I didn't get your last remark though (the superimposition trick). How would you superimpose two fullscreen backgrounds?

Comment: @julien_c: Basically, you apply the semi-transparent background image to `body` and the background color to `html`. I've added an example snippet.

Comment: Well, the background image does not repeat in that case, right? (I guess I should have specified a *repeated semi-transparent background image*) - Here's the page I'm trying to fix: http://www.twitpokerhq.com

Comment: (If your browser window is high enough, you'll see that the background image does not take up all the window's height.)

Comment: @julien_c: Oh, you can always have it repeat of course - mine was just an example based on one of my sites which doesn't use a repeating image. If the background image doesn't take up the entire height then that's where you need to set a min-height.

Comment: @BoltClock Got it, thanks! And updated my page. Isn't this effect gorgeous? :) Thanks again!

Comment: @julien_c: It looks great! It kind of reminds me of Game Center's poker table texture. Glad I helped :)

Comment: Note that html behaves with respect to the viewport in much the same way as body behaves with respect to html, with the background escaping beyond the confines of the html element. See http://jsfiddle.net/GmAL4/4/ to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks mate. +1 for greatly edited answer and providing spec reference. No wonder your reputation is high. :)

Comment: @Alohci: That is indubitable, but is it mentioned in the spec? I can't seem to find any references.

Comment: @BoltClock - I think it is this, from [CSS 2.1 14.2 The Background](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background) "The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and covers the entire canvas,..."

Comment: ... which also starts the first paragraph at the link which you provide at the top of your answer.

Comment: @Alohci: That's me, always neglecting to pick the most obvious starting point to look... I suppose it'd be appropriate to include it in the blockquote.

Comment: @BoltClock This is one of the best answers I've ever seen on Stack Overflow and I've seen many. Great work!

Answer (score 9):

Suggest reading this:

https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/

Essentially, in the absence of a `background` on the `html` element, the `body` `background` will cover the page. If there is a `background` on the `html` element, the `body` `background` behaves just like any other element.