# Background image referenced in external css is not loading

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I have this in an external css file, but its not working at all. I would assume I'd written it wrong, but when placed internally, it works fine. Any ideas as to what might be going on?

```
html
{
background-image:url(images/background-grid.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

Comment: Is your css file in a folder?

Comment: Please show your HTML that you are using to load this external CSS file. Thanks.

Comment: If an answer helped it's a 'common' rule to accept it

Answer (score 6):

I assume your CSS file is in a folder like this.

```
    /
        css/
            yourcss.css
        images/
            background-grid.jpg
        index.html
```

The paths given in your CSS file are **relative to the path of the CSS file** (in the example I given, the `css` folder). So you should use `..`:

```
background-image: url(../images/background-grid.jpg);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you didn't write it completely wrong

But it's better to use body instead of html.

**Explanation why to use body**

*It allows you to use an overlay on top of that body tag. Like a grid-ish background on the body and a shade on the side. But both are correct. Depending on what you are trying to do ofc.*

*If you don't repeat your background there is a possibility that your picture doesn't use the whole page and then you should use the html tag. But in this case it gives the same solution because of that repeat.*

[SO replay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body/10947583#10947583): tnx to attronics

**Explanation of your 'error'**

If your images are in a different folder than your html page (which should be the case).
You should use `..` as relative path to your css file.

Without the `..` it would mean that you are going to look for that image in the same folder as your html page.

```
body{
  background-image:url(../images/background-grid.jpg);
  background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

Here is a site that gives some [Basics of CSS](http://www.cssbasics.com/introduction-to-css/). Didn't check the source though.

Comment: It's indeed better to use body to start your css.

Comment: +1, basically the same as my answer. Why do you say he should use `body` instead? In the current state of your answer, you are only spreading one more myth without an explanation.

Comment: Indeed both answered at the same time too. Well it allows him to use an overlay on top of that body tag. Like a grid-ish background on the body and a shade on the side. But both are correct. Depending on what he's trying to do ofc. If he doesn't repeat his background there is a possibility that his picture doesn't use the whole page and then you should use the html tag. But in this case it gives the same solution.

Comment: Yes. That's why I'm saying the sentence `But it's better to use body instead of html.` and then `it's better to use body` is simply wrong in its current form. Either put in an explanation, or simply remove that whole part. (also, I know we have answered at the same time, I just said that I'm upvoting, because your answer is just as good as mine)

Comment: Tnx for pointing out the fail grammar. I'm also upvoting you because indeed it's the same.

Comment: @Liquid, this is a great [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10947583/1195891) that describes your point of view for body and html when used with a background image. Cheers!

Comment: @attronics indeed it describes it pretty well. :) tnx

Answer (score 2):

It may be your folder structure, try

```
html
{
background-image:url(../images/background-grid.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to ../images/background-grid.jpg, it worked perfectly. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Don't forget to look into the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

When we have these folders

```
css
img
and index.html
```

when we write css in style tag in index page which is called internal css then it works right but when we right css in `styles.css` in css folder then background img does not work.

because you move with in folder and path of background img does not work. so you have to write like this:

```
background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
```

then it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

`..` this mean go one level up.

So, if your folder structure is like this:

```
image/
     background.png
css/
    stylesheet.css
```

then your css rule should be like this:

```
html {
background-image: url('../image/background.png');
}
```

If your folder structure is like this:

```
style/
     image/
           bgr/
               background.png
     css/
         deeper/
               stylesheet.css
```

then, go up two levels to the image directory like below:

```
 html {
    background-image: url('../../image/bgr/background.png');
 }
```

And so on. Just add up the `..` followed by trailing slash `/`.