# Body background in Chrome disregarding position of body

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When you move the body element on a particular page in Chrome (testing v23) using `position: relative; top: 100px;` as example, the background is still applied to the whole viewport.

Is this a Chrome bug or could anyone explain the behavior / supply a flexible solution?

Comment: Is this strict or quirks mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually expected behavior for all browsers: while the `body` element is indeed being offset 100 pixels from the top, the background itself is being seamlessly propagated to the viewport as described in the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body/10947583#10947583). It's probably a holdover from the era of HTML presentational attributes, where setting background attributes on `body` allowed the background to be propagated to the viewport, giving an appearance of applying a background to the whole page.

If you want to restrict the background to only the `body` element, simply give `html` a background color that is anything other than `transparent`, or give it a background image. The viewport will then use the background of `html` instead.