# height: 100% or min-height: 100% for html and body elements?

Tags: html, css

While designing layouts I set the `html, body` elements' `height` to `100%` but in some cases, this fails, so what should be used?

```css
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

or

```css
html, body {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Well, this is not opinion based as each method has its own flaws, so what's the recommended way to go for and why?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

If you're trying to apply background images to `html` and `body` that fill up the entire browser window, neither. Use this instead:

```css
html {
   height: 100%;
}

body {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

My reasoning is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body/10947583#10947583) (where I explain holistically how to apply backgrounds in this manner):

> Incidentally, the reason why you have to specify `height` and `min-height` to `html` and `body` respectively is because neither element has any intrinsic height. Both are `height: auto` by default. It is the viewport that has 100% height, so `height: 100%` is taken from the viewport, then applied to `body` as a minimum to allow for scrolling of content.

The first way, using `height: 100%` on both, prevents `body` from expanding with its contents once they start to grow beyond the viewport height. Technically this doesn't *prevent* the content from scrolling, but it does cause `body` to leave a gap beneath the fold, which is usually undesirable.

The second way, using `min-height: 100%` on both, doesn't cause `body` to expand to the full height of `html` because `min-height` with a percentage doesn't work on `body` unless `html` has an explicit `height`.

For the sake of completeness, [section 10 of CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html) contains all the details, but it's an *extremely* convoluted read so you can skip it if you're not interested in anything beyond what I've explained here.

Comment: This is what I liked this most :) `height: 100% is taken from the viewport, then applied to body as a minimum to allow for scrolling of content` easy peasy solution... thanks //

Comment: I wonder though, how does the scroll bars magically appear then? The `html` element has `overflow:visible` by default, so I assume the scroll bars appear due to browser behavior to allow the whole normal flow of the document to be displayed.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté: It translates to `overflow: auto` on the viewport, which is where the scrollbars come from. That's covered in section 11: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html

Comment: Wow quick reply, thanks for the direct link to spec as well. `=]`

Comment: @BoltClock Any idea how to get the child 100% of the body [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpDLw/)? [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpDLw/1/) works though

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Did you find any solution? I despair here :/

Comment: @Julian He had edited his answer after I had commented, you will get the answer in there, use `background` on `html` and not on any container element

Comment: Thanks, @Mr.Alien, but the background should shrink horizontally with the window in a specified range. Sometimes I hate designers... :) Thanks, though

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, despite there being lots of other answers to similar questions on here.

Comment: By the way..maybe do not forget to put the `box-sizing:border-box;` on all html to elements, to avoid issues with margins and paddings here and there :)

Comment: box-sizing: border-box doesn't affect margins. Padding, yeah, but that's down to personal preference.

Answer (score 24):

You can use viewport height (`vh`) unit:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

It is relative to screen, not to parent height, so you don't need html height: 100%.

Comment: What extra advantages does this offer though.

Comment: No extra advantages, just another way to solve the problem.

Comment: beware of how mobile understands this

Comment: Just be aware that no all browsers support this units...
Do check browser compatibility first: https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: A warning: viewport-relative units don't take into account scroll bar dimensions. You may end up with an extra few pixels of white space at the bottom of your content, if the page width is overflowing.