# 100% height div with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a full height website but it seem twitter make issue with body min-height 100%

here my css :

```
html{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    min-height:100%
}
#main{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

and here my HTML :

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main" class="container">
            ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want my #main div always same height that browser if content is smaller than browser but I want my div will highter than browser if my content is bigger.

With my code, #main div always take height of my content and don't adjust to my browser size if i have a small content.

Why ?!

Comment: Have you tried. min-height: 100vh; vh stands for windows height

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555682/height-100-or-min-height-100-for-html-and-body-elements

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this CSS.

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
  min-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some extra css to your code.

```
#main {
min-height:100%;
}

body, html {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

i hope this is what you're looking for if, not try explain me what happens ;)!

Comment: If I fix my body height to 100%, my content overflows of my body when content is long.
I want my body have at least the same height that browser but un unlimited height if my content is to long

Answer (score 0):

Just add below CSS and you will be done :

```
body, html {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```