# Body at 100% and min-height of 100% but content extends past browser screen

Tags: html, css

I know I've seen the solution to this issue but I can't find it for the life of me.

I've got the html and body elements extended to 100% of the dom. They also have a min-height of 100%. The problem is when my content extends past the bottom of the browser screen the body won't extend with it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Damn you body, extend!!</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html,body{
                height     :100%;
                min-height :100%;
            }
            html{
                background-color:gray;
            }
            body{
                width            :90%;
                margin           :auto;
                background-color :white;
            }
            body > div{
                background-color :red;
                height           :50px;
                width            :80px;
                margin           :auto;
                text-align       :center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
      <div>testitem <br />testItem</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I could have sworn the min-height would cause the body to extend to fit the content but I'm obviously wrong. Could someone point it out really quick??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should work fine if you just set a `min-height`:

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/7hg7m

Comment: Right, that's what I thought it was. that's the first css rule declared in my example above.

Comment: Ah, I see what it was. The hight and min-height were conflicting. I removed the height rule and it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: *You can eat minimum 2 apples* AND *You will eat 2 apples* So, if you are a good boy you will eat 2 apples in the end, neither 3, nor more. :-)

Comment: There's a specific combination of `height: 100%` and `min-height: 100%` for html and body that I recommend here, with an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555682/height-100-or-min-height-100-for-html-and-body-elements

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
html,body {
  /* height: 100%; */
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `height` property because you already set `min-height` property otherwise there may have conflict. Hope it helps!