# error min-height and margin-right and

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having some problems with the css of a site I'm developing. It is a shop that uses wordpress woocommerce. When I try to enable the "min-height" to 100% this error happens.

```
html, body, #bodychild{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Another problem is that incomandando me is: When the browser window is resized it happens: 
[image]

And there is still a margin to mistoria right that I can not remove.
[image]

> > **[See the online site!](http://portaldoapicultor.com.br/loja/)** <<

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555682/height-100-or-min-height-100-for-html-and-body-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution of the second problem is in your css. Width of #footercontainer i set to 100% and left margin 10px. Because of that whole div is wider than screen for 10px.

Solution:

```
    #footercontainer {

         padding: 20px 0px 15px 0;
         margin-left: 0px;
         padding-left: 1%;
         width: 99%;
                     }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really had not realized it. It works. Now tell me you would know why a margin so big so when I resize the browser?

Comment: that's because it's not responsive. You set the witdh of #bodychid to over 1000px, and when the browser resizes, it is still over 1000px, and viewport is less than 400px.
You need to set media queries in your css for theme to be responsive. If you need help with that i'll write you a code