# Is using position: relative on html tag advised?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I just found out a solution for creating sticky footers:

```
html {
    position: relative;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Though I am wondering on how advised it is to put `position:relative` on the `html` tag.

The way I understand it: instead of `position: absolute` being relative to the viewport, it becomes relative to the document.

Is this good practice?

Comment: If it works for you, it's a good practice. There is nothing wrong to style `html` elements, it the same as styling other ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the root element `html` is stylable by CSS just like any other element, certain properties may behave differently by virtue of it being the root element. `position` is one of those properties: in particular the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position) has this to say:

> User agents may treat position as 'static' on the root element.

As far as I know, no modern browser *actually* does this, but it's still not guaranteed that `position: relative` will always work on the root element. In your case, you can simply avoid this by setting `position: relative` on the `body` element instead of the `html` element:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Note that the footer will not stick to the bottom of the page if the body does not reach the height of the viewport (e.g. when there is not enough content in the page). If this is an issue for you, set `height` and `min-height` on `html` and `body` following the instructions in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555682/height-100-or-min-height-100-for-html-and-body-elements/17555766#17555766):

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed to know; additionnally, could you acknowledge my thought on that trick making `position: absolute` relative to document instead of viewport? That would help me understanding the thing better. Also, I had put `min-height` already, just forgot to  put it in the example.

Comment: @Angivare: Your understanding is correct, for as long as the position property isn't forced to be static anyway.

Comment: @Angivare: I rejected your edit because my code does not match the code that you have - notice that I set `min-height` on *`body`*, not `html`. Setting `min-height` on `html` alone has no effect.

Comment: Oh right, that's important enough to point out. Thank you for your answer anyway