# How to make div always fill entire viewport, but allow scrolling if content is bigger?

Tags: html, css

I tried the following (described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555682/height-100-or-min-height-100-for-html-and-body-elements)):

```
<html style="height: 100%">
  <body style="min-height: 100%; margin: 0">
    <div style="min-height: 100%; background: red">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Without doctype header, it works as expected - div fills the entire screen and expands if needed. But if I add `<!DOCTYPE html>`, it stops working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to apply overflow:auto and More specific if want scroll on horizontal use overflow-x:auto vice-versa for vertical.

```
<html style="height: 100%">
  <body style="min-height: 100%; overflow:auto;  margin: 0">
    <div style="min-height: 100%; background: red">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T2EY0G4Z3X4FOQmjgV1K?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Change `min-height: 100%` of body to `height: 100%`.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: orange;
}

div
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: cyan
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This any good for you? I've overlayed a div with `position: absolute`, then made it scrollable on the y-axis.