# StellarJs parallax background image not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, stellar.js

I know there are other similar questions on this, believe me, I have been at this for almost two days now.

I am trying to use StellarJs to create a parallax background image in the header of my website. Unfortunately, it is having no effect whatsoever on the element with the specified `data-stellar-background-ratio`.

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/samrap/wLz9drmw/) (with a different bg image than on my local machine).

I even made a version exactly like the example on the website and it still would not work. I looked into solutions on 4 other similar questions, none of which helped me. I’m at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After punching a few holes in the drywall I realized that the problem had nothing to do with the element in question or the way I was calling the stellar function. It had to do with this little piece of CSS right here:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It seems you cannot apply a height of 100% to the `html` and `body` tags, because after removing that height declaration, it works like a charm! I'm so confused as to why, and I will be contacting the creator of StellarJs to see if it is a bug or if it is intentional/expected behavior for some reason that I am overlooking.

The work-around for the height 100% issue can be found here: [height: 100% or min-height: 100% for html and body elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555682/height-100-or-min-height-100-for-html-and-body-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I can't speak to your local copy but I know that at least this one [I fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/j9xsoqp2/) by moving the Stellar source code to an external resource and then adding a missing `);` at the end of the `$(document).ready()` function and fixing that syntax error. You may want to check your local version to see if you have something similar, and check your [dev tools' console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) to see if there are any syntax issues you're missing.

Comment: The missing `);` was an accident when I copy pasted into JSFiddle. I tried using stellar as an external resource instead of directly from my file system and still no luck. I can't understand why, I have the exact thing that works on jsfiddle

Comment: Without seeing any more of the code then there's not much help to be given here; is there more you can show?