# responsive image resizing not working

Tags: html, css

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The code above resizes the images width with the with of the page, while keeping the same ratio with the height.

Why doesn't

```
img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

resize the image's height with the pages height, while keeping the same ratio with the width? Is there another way I can have that effect on my image?

Comment: I think it does https://jsfiddle.net/q3os7gfw/

Comment: Why did you set the `html, body` height to 100%? It made the code work, but why?

Comment: Well if you set `height: 100%` on `img` then you also must set 100% height on all parents in this case html and body,  Both are height: auto by default. It is the viewport that has 100% height, so height: 100% is taken from the viewport, then applied to body as a minimum to allow for scrolling of content. More here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555682/height-100-or-min-height-100-for-html-and-body-elements

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS – why doesn’t percentage height work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-why-doesn-t-percentage-height-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be `height` is not defined of parent of `img`. So please put any `height` to the parent of `img` then try.

Comment: That was the problem as @NenadVracar stated above