# Why doesn't background-size: 100% 100% work anymore in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm quite simply trying to achieve a body background image that always in its entirety fills the browser window (aspect ratio doesn't matter).

The standard css code

```
 body{
     background-image: url('test.jpg');
     background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
```

seems to work fine in almost all modern major browsers, including Firefox 45. But in the newest Firefox, 52, the background-image gets clipped to a very narrow band in the vertical direction, which is then repeated until it fills the window. Am I using some deprecated code I'm not aware of, or is this a Firefox bug?

Comment: Firefox 49 and later also implement this property prefixed with -webkit.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: That's just to support sites that were designed solely for WebKit for no real reason and therefore omit the unprefixed background-size property. background-size has been supported unprefixed by Firefox for many, many years. Authors are supposed to work under the assumption that Firefox *doesn't* support -webkit-background-size, because in an ideal world it has no reason to.

Comment: Yes, note the "also implement" in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the spec's definition for `background-size`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size):

> A percentage is relative to the background positioning area.

And from [section 3.11.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds) (emphasis mine):

> **3.11.1. The Canvas Background and the Root Element**
>
> The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and its background painting area extends to cover the entire canvas. **However, any images are sized and positioned relative to the root element as if they were painted for that element alone. (In other words, the background positioning area is determined as for the root element.)** The root element does not paint this background again, i.e., the used value of its background is transparent.

You're applying the background to `body`, but that makes no difference; section 3.11.2 simply says "the propagated values are treated as if they were specified on the root element."

So it looks like Firefox has simply updated its behavior to be more standards-compliant (I don't know if a Bugzilla ticket exists for this; I haven't been able to find one). The background positioning area of the root element in an empty HTML document in standards mode should be zero, since the height of the root element in such a document should be zero, meaning percentage values of `background-size` should resolve to zero. Firefox 52 still appears to enforce an 8-pixel minimum height on the root element for some reason, resulting in the very narrow band that you see with `background-size: 100% 100%`, but I guess that is a separate issue.

So basically this means in order for `background-size: 100%` to work on either `html` or `body`, you need to specify 100% height for the root element, in a similar vein to my answer to [height: 100% or min-height: 100% for html and body elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555682/height-100-or-min-height-100-for-html-and-body-elements/17555766#17555766) (except the `min-height` on `body` is not necessary since you're only applying a single background, to the `body` element alone, which is subject to the propagating behavior described in §3.11.2)

Or you can choose to apply `min-height: 100vh` to the `body` element instead as Michael Coker demonstrates, but that's assuming you're going to remove the default margins while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

The second value in `background-size` is the height. Set a `height` on body or add some content and it works fine.

```css
body {
  background: url('http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
background: url(test.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 100%;
```

Hope this works.