# Multiple backgrounds and color opacity

Tags: html, css

im trying to figure something out.

i have a simple webpage with a pattern background that is repeated, what i want to do in css is create a color overlay using multiple backgrounds. my code is this.

```
html,body {
background: 
rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5),
url(../img/background.png) repeat;
}
```

however it makes nothing show, just a white screen, if i switch the background positions and put the image on top then i can see it does find the image and displays that but obviously with no color overlay.

did i miss something in how i think this should be working? does it not work on the html,body tags?

any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Nick

Comment: Have you tried just background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5) url(../img/background.png) repeat; (without the "," between the rgba and the url ? Not sure what you want to do. This should render your background image with full opacity and your color with 0.5 opacity

Comment: Pierre is right, if it works. The background image has priority over the color. So naturally, a color overlay isn't gonna work out. But when you set the opacity of the Background to 0,5, you allow half of the coloed background to shine through, which makes it look like there is a color overlay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rgba()` is a [color value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color). [You can only have a color value in the last background layer](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background); specifying a color on any other layers makes the syntax invalid.<sup>1</sup>

If you need to overlay the background image with a semitransparent color, the only workaround for one element is to create an image of that color and overlay that instead. But since you're trying to apply a page background, you should be able to simply apply the color overlay to `body` and the image to `html`:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../img/background.png) repeat;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5);
}
```

Just keep in mind that `body` needs to cover the entire area of `html` as well, otherwise your color will only overlay part of the background image. The `height` and `min-height` styles above enforce this for height; for width, you will need to make sure `body` does not have any side margins or a width that's less than 100%.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body/10947583#10947583) for a more extensive write-up on both approaches to `html` and `body` backgrounds.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>It's understandably puzzling why colors are forbidden from any layer except the bottom one considering that color values with alpha channels exist and that you can still work around it with an *image* with the same alpha channels and the browser would still have to composite the background anyway. But that's just how it is, I guess. It doesn't look like this limitation is going to be addressed in Backgrounds level 4 either, so what do I know.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for descriptive and fast reply, its working 100% now and i fully understand it. greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use trick with gradient:

```css
html,body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5) 0%, rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5) 100%), url(../img/background.png) repeat;
}
```

Put desired color to both gradient values