# Declaring html body in css

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have used

```
html, body {
 background-image: something;
}
```

in my CSS for many years. Now I can't remember why really..

Is that method even necessary/beneficial or is **body {}** enough?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're applying a background, selecting `body` is usually enough; the browser will know to paint the background over the entire viewport regardless of the body dimensions. The details of how a browser is expected to behave are covered in the spec ([CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#background), [CSS3 module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds)). Even the CSS2.1 spec recommends it (although it doesn't mandate it for reasons mentioned later in the prose):

> For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element.

The only situation in which you would apply a background to both elements is when you want to layer one background over a different one; you could either use the CSS3 syntax of layered backgrounds on just the `body` element, or have `body`'s background overlay that of `html`. Even then, the only reason I can think of for choosing the latter is if you need compatibility with older browsers that don't support the CSS3 syntax. I cover both methods in-depth in my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body).