# position:absolute makes an hr element more than 100% wide

Tags: html, css

In FX and IE the following code makes two bars, but the blue one is slightly wider than the browser screen. Any resizing will leave a horizontal scrollbar with the tail of the blue bar offscreen to the left. This is boiled down from a much larger page and I can't remove the position:absolute element in the original. Can anyone figure out how to make the blue bar only 100% wide so it matches the red one and doesn't cause a horizontal scrollbar? Any ideas what's behind this behavior? I'm stumped. Thanks very much.

```html
<hr style="border:1px solid red; width:100%;"/>
<hr style="position:absolute; border:1px solid blue; width:100%;" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply:

```
body {position:relative;}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/qyvtzyfh/

**Reason:**

In a very short simplified description, `position:absolute;` and `width:100%;` on the element make the width of the element relative to the immediate parent with an explicitly defined `position:relative;` or `position:absolute;`, in your case since you don't have it, it gets the width of the initial containing block (which contains the `html` element as well) instead of the `body`, by adding `position:relative;` to `body` you make the width of the element relative to `body` (besides its position).

Comment: In fact, if there's no ancestor element having a `position` of anything other than `static`, `absolute` positioned elements will respect to the **initial containing block** - not the `<html>` element itself - in which the root element sits; If you give an explicit width the `<html>` element, [you'll see](http://jsbin.com/hugede/1/edit) an `absolute`ly positioned element having `right: 0` declaration doesn't respect the width of `<html>` element. You could find more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25866405/1725764)

Comment: @HashemQolami True, that's why I said "In a very short simplified description", talking about the specific code situation of the OP, not the general definitions of the box model, but I updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: @Arbel Thanks for the update. I understand your point of view. However IMO it might cause a misunderstanding which probably would lead the readers to trouble.

Comment: @HashemQolami You are welcome, I respectfully agree and abide by your opinion :)

Comment: Thanks for the information! W3Schools says that it will revert to the <html>. And this does appear to be true. I stumbled across a solution, which was to add style="margin:0" to the body tag. So the first HR appeared to honor a default margin on the body, while the second, absolute one skipped back to the html tag, which had no default margin. That's my guess. At any rate the margin:0 made it work. I'm going to mess with the solutions you gave. Thanks, all.

Comment: @rdgWarren You are welcome. Keep in mind that in your situation margin:0 actually just makes the issue 'not apparent' since it will hide the differences in the parents' widths, but it's not a fundamental solution.

Comment: @Arbel I [tried to edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5796363) to show a [stack snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1) of the answer so the demo would be available in-page, but it was rejected because the suggested edits review queue doesn't show stack snippets properly. You might be interested in adding it yourself; I think this is a good type of post for it as the demo is very simple.