# Why does percentage width work even if no explicit width value given for containing block?

Tags: html, css, width

According to specifications for `height` the element's containing box needs to have an explicit `height` in order for percentage height to work on the element (i.e. a numerical value of `100%` height used on all parent containing boxes).

However why do the same rules not seem to apply for percentage `width`s? When I set a percentage `width` on an element with a containing box that has no explicit `width`, it still seems to change the width of the element. (see example)

```css
.first {
    background-color: teal;
}
.second {
    background-color: gold;
    width: 30%;  /* the '.second' box becomes narrower! */
    height: 40%; /* <-- doesn't have any effect         */
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    ""
    <div class="second">
    ""
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to know why you don't have to set a width for block level elements like the div?

Comment: yes, how does the nested div with width 50% know what value it should take 50% of? Since the containing block has no explicit width set on it (i.e. no width 100% derived from the body and no explicit px width)

Comment: That's because it's a block level element, all block level elements in HTML have a default width of 100% that's why they span across the width of the browser window. Inline elements like images, and links don't, they just extend to their contents length.

Comment: 100% of what? If I make the body the containing box the .second does not fill 100% of the body as would be expected:                                        .first {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%
}
.second {
    background-color: yellow;
}

Comment: of the parent element. http://jsfiddle.net/usvgfse2/1/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Non-replaced block-level elements which are in normal flow take the `width` of their parent.

Well, that's a [lie-to-children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children)!

In order to understand what happens under the hood, we should start from how [`width` of a non-replaced block-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth) is calculated.

> **[10.3.3 Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth)**
>
> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other
>   properties:
>
> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' +
>   'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of
>   [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details)
>
> [...] If 'width' is set to 'auto', any other 'auto' values become '0'
>   and 'width' follows from the resulting equality.

Due to the fact that the initial value of `width` property is `auto`, the `width` of a block-level element would be the same as its containing block.

`<html>` is a block-level element and it lives in the [initial containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details).

The initial containing block is a rectangular box which [takes the width of the viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866303/why-bottom-positioned-footer-inside-html-moves-below-viewport-if-html-height/25866405#25866405). Hence the width of `<html>` element would be equal to the width of the viewport.

On the other hand, the containing block of `<body>` element is generated by `<html>`. Therefore they would have equal widths as well.

`<body>` itself establishes a containing block for its block-level children. And that's why a `<div>` element in normal flow will take the width of the viewport.

W3C indicates it better:

> With no positioning, the containing blocks (C.B.) in the following
>   document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Illustration of containing blocks</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY id="body">
      <DIV id="div1">
      <P id="p1">This is text in the first paragraph...</P>
      <P id="p2">This is text <EM id="em1"> in the 
      <STRONG id="strong1">second</STRONG> paragraph.</EM></P>
      </DIV>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

> are established as follows:

```
For box generated by    C.B. is established by
html                    initial C.B. (UA-dependent)
body                    html
div1                    body
p1                      div1
p2                      div1
em1                     p2
strong1                 p2
```

---

However that is not true for `height` of non-replaced block-level elements <sup>(which are still in normal flow!)</sup>:

> **[10.6.3 Block-level non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' computes to 'visible'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#normal-block)**
>
> [...] If 'height' is 'auto', the height depends on whether the element
>   has any block-level children and whether it has padding or borders.
>
> [...] Only children in the normal flow are taken into account (i.e.,
>   floating boxes and absolutely positioned boxes are ignored, and
>   relatively positioned boxes are considered without their offset).

The initial value of `height` is `auto`, therefore if the block-level element doesn't have any block-level children, padding or border, the computed value of `height` would be `0`.

[That's true even for `<html>` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866303/why-bottom-positioned-footer-inside-html-moves-below-viewport-if-html-height/25866405#25866405).

Answer (score 0):

I think all block-elements has a 100% width if not anything else is specified. The height works differently, because if you don't set the height anywhere it just bases it's height on the total height of your content.