# HTML and BODY are static, which is my DIV's closest positioned ancestor?

Tags: html, css

I’ve got this simple HTML5 document:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      .parent1 { height: 50px; background: #00ff00; }
      .parent1 > .child1 { height: 50%; width: 100%; background: #ffcc00; }
      .parent2 { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 25%; background: #ff0000; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent1">
      <div class="child1">I'm 25px height (50% of 50px)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent2">I'm absolute positioned. My ancestors, body and html, are static... Where I'm getting the 25% from?</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

There’s no height defined for **html** and **body**, so they use the default value auto (which means that their height is their content’s height). They aren’t positioned, so they are static.

**div.parent1** is 50px height.

**div.parent1** has a child element with a 50% height.

**div.parent2** is positioned absolute with a height of 25%.

If I’m not mistaken, a height set with percentage only works if it’s parent has a height defined (that’s the case of **div.child1**).

Because **div.parent2** is absolute, it’s height is not computed, so **body** and **html** height is 50px. That’s clear, but I don’t understand why **div.parent2** 25%’s height is working… Where does it take from? Its ancestors body and html are static… Window? Viewport?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mm3r6s96/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does percentage width work even if no explicit width value given for containing block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353625/why-does-percentage-width-work-even-if-no-explicit-width-value-given-for-contain)

Comment: Similar question can be found here as well: [CSS – why doesn’t percentage height work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-why-doesn-t-percentage-height-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `html` 'element' in the absence of an positioned ancestor.

> For an absolutely positioned element, percentage values for the left, right and width properties are relative to the width of the containing block. Percentage values for the top, bottom and **height properties** are relative to the height of the containing block.

In this case, the [**containing block**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#containing-block) is the `html` element,

The body had no height as the element is out of the flow.

```css
html {
  background: green;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}
.parent2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent2">I'm absolute positioned. My ancestors, body and html, are static... Where I'm getting the 25% from?</div>
```

Comment: And html gets width/height from viewport?

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for. Maybe you should add this info about the viewport to the answer

Comment: The others have covered that...i don't want to steal their thunder.

Comment: It isn't the html element. See https://jsfiddle.net/kp3e4mgr/. The html element is the yellow box. The initial containing block is the html element's container.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what w3 says about absolutely positioned elements:

> They define a new rectangular plane into which their contents are
>   flowed, just as the HTML inside the `<BODY>` element flows into the
>   default container.

So it sounds like the `body` element itself represents a default container, no matter it is static.

Taken from [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-positioning-970131#Positioned).

Or even better explanation from [w3 wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning).

> If an absolutely positioned element has no positioned ancestor, then
>   the containing block is something called the “initial containing
>   block,” which in practice equates to the html element. If you are
>   looking at the web page on screen, this means the browser window; if
>   you are printing the page, it means the page boundary.

Comment: Thanks, the w3 wiki much better!

Comment: No,  the initial containing block does NOT equate to the html element, it's the html element's container. The initial containing block is the height of the viewport. the html element's height is its specified height, or if auto, the height of its contents.

Answer (score 1):

`html` is a block-level element and it lives in the initial containing block.

The initial containing block is a rectangular box which takes the width of the viewport. Hence the width of `html` element would be equal to the width of the viewport.

On the other hand, the containing block of `body` element is generated by `html`. Therefore they would have equal widths as well.

`body` itself establishes a containing block for its block-level children. And that's why a `div` element in normal flow will take the width of the viewport.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354270/2543240

Answer (score -1):

Your **HTML** is static using **px**.
The percentage is calculated on browser page **height** - **width**

Comment: It should be `width`, not `weight`.