# Why some html and body properties have this behaviour?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand a few things.

### First question:

Why there is a `margin-top` on the `body`?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
```

If I look with dev tool inspector in Chrome, it shows me that the `h1` top margin starts outside the `body` top margin (picture shows the `h1` highlighted):

[image]

### Second question:

In the next example, why does the yellow color is drawn outside the `body`?

I expected to see yellow color only within the `body` element, given that I set `overflow` property:

```css
body {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

## Third question

If I add a `background-color` on the `html` element, it works, the yellow color fills only the `body` element, why?

```css
html {
  background-color: red;
}
body {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I always use `position: relative` on the `body` so it's less confusing.

Comment: The first question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work The second and third questions are duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body

Comment: That said, you should post your answer to your first question as an actual answer, rather than editing it into the question.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for posting that SO question, it is indeed my 1st question. I had a brain freeze about margin collapsing, I completely forgot about it. Therefore, I didn't know what to search for first. Thanks again.

Comment: @dippas dude, why did you delete your answer !? Disappointing... You provided good fixes, it's just that I was also looking to understand the **why** part too not just how to fix it

Comment: @MikeFills because as boltclock pointed out my answers aren't fully correct.. Therefore it's better not to misguide you and future readers

Answer (score 1):

**Your First Question**

> Why there is a margin-top on the body?

**Answer Is**
It is because of h1 tag, h1 takes margin from top and bottom. Your point is appriciatable that html (red color) is showing.
Its the default behavior. it will work fine when you add float to h1

```
h1{float: left;}
```

**Your Second Question**

> I expected to see yellow color only within the body element, given
>   that I set overflow property

**Answer Is**

overflow only works when you apply fix width/height to any tag/class.

if you apply overflow hidden to html/body it doesn't works, i think its the default behavior of the browser like firefox as well as others may be. Because same thing happened to me as well.

Third Questions answer also summarized in Answer of Second Question

i hope it would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Set margin: 0 to h1 and add padding instead, will solve your issue.

Comment: If you add this:

    <h1 style="margin:0;padding:20px">Hello Plunker!</h1>

the top-margin disappears. Answer to question 1.