# background-image allowed on root element <html>?

Tags: css, html

In a project that I was assigned to fix some stuff in, I just stumbled upon this:

```
<html lang="de" style="background-image: url(assets/img/detail_bg.jpg);">
```

To me it feels plain wrong to apply a background-image on the root element; I'd rather put this on the `body` instead, or even further down the DOM in a wrapping `div`.

Yet I wasn't able to find information on this.

Can anyone shed some light as of what is allowed/recommended/discouraged to do on the root element? Links very welcome.

Comment: Its perfectly fine to use on the `<html>` tag. There are not any disadvantages.

Comment: You can find proper explanation of when to use background-image to <html> or <body> here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body

Comment: Applying it to `<html>` will work due to the generous nature of browsers, but as per the [official spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds): "It is recommended that authors of HTML documents specify the canvas background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element."