# How to add background image in html? No repeat image

Tags: html

I set picture using body background="image path";

But it is not showing output properly.

What will change in code?

Comment: Let me google this for you: https://www.google.com/search?dcr=0&source=hp&ei=Ss1LWqbvCcS1sAeMuKGoBA&q=How+to+add+background+image+in+html&oq=How+to+add+background+image+in+html&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.2302.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.WxuZs4ZsjXQ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying a background to <html> and/or <body>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not even show the slightest effort to solve the problem before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
style="backgroud:url(img path) no-repeat"
```