# Why HTML body margin area is filled with the body's background-color?

Tags: html, css

Why HTML body margin area is filled with the body's background-color which is different behavior than for other elements (e.g. div)? Is this specified somewhere? Below is a simple example.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 25px solid black;
}

div {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 25px solid brown;
  background-color: orange;
  background-position: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Have a look at [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

Comment: What colour would you like it to be? You could always add  * {background-color: white;} to the top of your css code

Comment: This is not about collapsing margins, that's a different thing. In my case the coloring happens horizontally too (collapsing margins occurs top/bottom only).

Comment: Pretty well explained in the duplicate questions. Thanks @Temani Afif.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body