# Cannot apply CSS shake effect to body

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a class `image` which is added to the `body` using a jQuery function:

```
$('body').addClass('image').addClass('shake');
```

When I try to add a shake effect using class `shake` it doesn't give the shake effect:

```
$('body').addClass('image').addClass('shake');
```

How can I correct my code to get the shake effect for the image added to body? Is it a problem with jQuery or something else?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').addClass('image').addClass('shake');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Basic);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
}

.shake {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
}

.shake:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake-base;
  -ms-animation-name: shake-base;
  -webkit-animation-name: shake-base;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -ms-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake-base {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  2% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  4% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  6% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  8% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  12% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  14% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  16% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  18% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  22% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  24% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  26% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  28% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  32% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  34% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  36% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  38% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  42% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  44% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  46% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  48% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  52% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  54% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  56% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  58% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  62% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  64% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  66% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  68% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  72% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  74% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  76% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  78% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  82% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  84% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  86% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  88% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  92% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  94% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  96% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  98% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes shake-base {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  2% {
    -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  4% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  6% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  8% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  10% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  12% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  14% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  16% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  18% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  20% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  22% {
    -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  24% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  26% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  28% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  30% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  32% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  34% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  36% {
    -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  38% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  40% {
    -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  42% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  44% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  46% {
    -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  48% {
    -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  52% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  54% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  56% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  58% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  60% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  62% {
    -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  64% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  66% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  68% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  70% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  72% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  74% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  76% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  78% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  80% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  82% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  84% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  86% {
    -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  88% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  90% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  92% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  94% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  96% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  98% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
}

@keyframes shake-base {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  2% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  4% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  6% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  8% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  14% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  16% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  18% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  22% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  24% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  28% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  32% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  34% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  36% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  38% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  42% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  44% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  48% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  52% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  54% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  56% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  58% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  62% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  64% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  68% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  72% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  74% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  78% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  82% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  84% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  86% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  88% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  92% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  94% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  98% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also note that all those vendor prefixes are massive overkill; you don't need most of them.

Comment: Do not do this on the body element( I have gotten something like this to work once, but on html element I think).
Just use a wrapper div instead.
And add the class on load, not on doc ready.

Comment: I was ready to make a pen or you but damn, that keyframe declaration breaks my clipboard.
You can keep that much briefer

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan we can apply them to body, the body is simply invisible

Comment: @TemaniAfif I stand corrected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's working fine but [the background you see is moved to the canvas and no more belong to the body element.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body) and your body element has 0 height since there is no content inside it. What you see isn't the `body` element (this one is not visible) but the canvas (your browser window) that *has stolen* the background from the body.

Change the background of the `html` (so that the canvas take this one) and give `body` some height to see the effect:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').addClass('image').addClass('shake');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Basic);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
  height:200px;
}

html {
  background:red;
}

.shake {
  transform-origin: center center;;
}

.shake:hover {
  animation: shake-base 100ms infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes shake-base {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  2% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  4% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  6% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  8% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  14% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  16% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  18% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  22% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  24% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  28% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  32% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  34% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  36% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  38% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  42% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  44% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  48% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  52% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  54% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  56% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  58% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  62% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  64% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  68% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  72% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  74% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  78% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  82% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  84% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  86% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  88% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  92% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  94% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  98% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan canvas is *technically* the correct term but yes it's a bit confusing (I added *browser window* for better understanding)

Answer (score 2):

Well, here you go, I have created a pen anyway, without the CSS prefixes.

I have added the class `image` to the div,

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

added some CSS to the div

```
 .image {
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
 }
```

and add the class to the image via [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.image').addClass('shake');
 });
```

Full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image').addClass('shake');
});
```

```css
.image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
}

.shake {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
}

.shake:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake-base;
  -ms-animation-name: shake-base;
  -webkit-animation-name: shake-base;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -ms-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes shake-base {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  2% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  4% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  6% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  8% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  14% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  16% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  18% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  22% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  24% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  28% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  32% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  34% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  36% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  38% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  42% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  44% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  48% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  52% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  54% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  56% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  58% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  62% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  64% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  68% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  72% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  74% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  78% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  82% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  84% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  86% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  88% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  92% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  94% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  98% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your content inside a wrapper (the .body-content in the example) and apply the shake class to this element. You should also apply full height to html and the body.

Note that applying a shaking class to your whole body may have an undesired effect because its content overflows and this results into displaying the browsers scrollers.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body .body-content').addClass('image').addClass('shake');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Basic);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);

.image {
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
}

html{
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.body-content{
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}


.shake {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
}
.shake:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake-base;
  -ms-animation-name: shake-base;
  -webkit-animation-name: shake-base;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -ms-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake-base { 0% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
  2% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  4% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  6% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  8% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  10% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  12% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  14% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  16% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  18% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  20% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  22% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  24% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  26% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  28% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  30% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  32% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  34% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  36% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  38% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  40% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  42% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  44% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  46% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  48% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  52% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  54% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  56% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  58% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  62% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  64% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  66% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  68% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  70% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  72% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  74% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  76% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  78% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  82% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  84% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  86% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  88% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  90% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  92% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  94% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  96% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  98% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); } }

@-ms-keyframes shake-base { 0% { -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
  2% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  4% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  6% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  8% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  10% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  12% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  14% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  16% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  18% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  20% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  22% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  24% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  26% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  28% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  30% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  32% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  34% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  36% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  38% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  40% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  42% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  44% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  46% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  48% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  50% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  52% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  54% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  56% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  58% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  60% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  62% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  64% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  66% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  68% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  70% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  72% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  74% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  76% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  78% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  80% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  82% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  84% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  86% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  88% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  90% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  92% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  94% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  96% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  98% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); } }

@keyframes shake-base { 0% { transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
  2% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  4% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  6% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  8% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  10% { transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  12% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  14% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  16% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  18% { transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  20% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  22% { transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  24% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  26% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  28% { transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  30% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  32% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  34% { transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  36% { transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  38% { transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  40% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  42% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  44% { transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  46% { transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  48% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  50% { transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  52% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  54% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  56% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  58% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  60% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  62% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  64% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  66% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  68% { transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  70% { transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  72% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  74% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  76% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  78% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  80% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  82% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  84% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  86% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  88% { transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  90% { transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  92% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  94% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  96% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  98% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="body-content"></div>
</body>
```