# How to extend main div to full browser window height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page, for the most part, should be extending the main container div of my page to the full height of the window, although I must be missing something, as i believe all the right CSS elements needed are present.. Any Help?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Programming Languages Concept Home</title>
<link type="text/css" href="unicss.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="Script/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Script/main.js"></script>
<noscript>Your browser has javascript disabled, please turn it on then refresh to take full advantage of this site</noscript>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"><h1 class="headover">Home.</h1>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="gs4/home.html">Object Or.</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Java</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ATT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sprint</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">T-Mobile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="gs4/home.html">Array</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="gs4/verizon.html">Verizon</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ATT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sprint</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">T-Mobile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="container"><br><br><br><p style="color:#666; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; text-align:center; text-indent:5px; font-size:24px;"><b>Programming has many faces and names. Java, C++, Perl, HTML, are all languages that can be used to program, to solve a problem that the programmer needs to solve. The tools in a programmers tool book are the languages he knows, all with different syntax, and different ways of going about to reach a solution. Whether the programmer uses the easiest language, or the one he is most familiar with, it is all personal choice. Find all the history and information about any programming language right here to help you pick the language that best suits you.</b></p>
    <!--<button>Screenshots</button>
  <p id="hide">Pretend these are some images yo.</p>-->

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url(Images/backgroundmain.jpg);
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}

.headover{
    color:#333;
    float:right;
}
.headover:hover{
    color:white;
}

#gfamily{
    margin:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}

#header{
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#666;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:54px;
    display:block;
    min-width:1000px;
}

#container{
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin:auto;
    width:70%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}

.nav{
    margin-left:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#999;
}

.navigation {
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    margin-top:15px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

.navigation li {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
}

.navigation li a {
    background:#262626;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    padding:8px 7px 8px 7px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top:1px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
    color:#666;
}

.navigation ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    margin:0 0 0 -1px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
}

.navigation ul li {
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    border-top:none;
}

.navigation ul a {
    display:block;
    height:15px;
    padding:8px 7px 13px 7px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
}

.navigation ul a:hover {
    color:#666;
}

#hide{
    display:none;
}

#extlink{
    color:#666;
}
#extlink:hover{
    color:#333;
}

#pics:hover{
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#666;
    border:none;
}
#pics{
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    color:#666;
    background-color:white;
    border:none;
}
```

[image: This]

Comment: Give us a jsFiddle or jsBin.

Comment: @kehrk that is not required for an answer on stack overflow.

Comment: But it helps. How could you possibly discourage somebody from doing so? @ErikPhilips

Comment: here you are http://jsfiddle.net/sC9mk/

Comment: @kehrk it was your phrasing.  A more practical comment might have been *Thanks for including your code, but to help others answer your question, I would recommend using jsfiddle.net or jsBin.com*.  Instead your comment sounds more like a demand of *gimme teh code, i too important to do it myself*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you need the following CSS:

```
html,body {
height:100%;
{
```

Your `body` will only fill up what the html fills and the html does not appear to be 100%.

Comment: Check out [What is the difference between applying css rules to html tag compared to body tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739601/what-is-the-difference-between-applying-css-rules-to-html-tag-compared-to-body-t).

Answer (score 3):

I've added

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
}
```

to your CSS, as highlighted in this bin: http://jsbin.com/wefir/1/edit

Also check this SO post for more info: [Make body have 100% of the browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)