# Margin, Padding, Height & width of html and body tags

Tags: html, css

I wrote this code in order to understand what does it margin, padding and position for the below code. the question are between these `/* */`. Thanks again.

```css
html {
  width: auto;
  /* Does auto apply the background-color automatically to the display screen */
  height: 100%;
  /* 100% means 100% of the display browser??*/
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  /*does changing the value of the margin will change anything in the page*/
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  Padding-bottom: 0%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 50%;
  /* does it means 50% of the width stated above in the html (auto)*/
  height: 50%;
  /*does it means 50% of the height of the display browser or we have to add the padding-top(1%) in html*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  /* does it mean that the body is shifted to below 25% of it's heigh or 25% of the display browser? */
  left: 25%;
  /*  what is the different if i give 0% to left and i changed the margin-left value to 25%*/
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

header {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  /* what does it mean here the value given to top and left??*/
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 5px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1> MY First webpage </h1>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Centering an item within the body is a simple combination of width and margins.

The margin applied below. `margin: 0 auto;` is shorthand for:

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
```

Centered `div.wrapper` width a width of `960px`

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* REMOVE THE MARGIN FROM THE BODY */
}

.wrapper {
  width: 960px; /* GIVE THE WRAPPING ELEMENT A WIDTH */
  margin: 0 auto; /* USE MARGIN (0 AUTO) TO CENTER THE WRAPPER ON THE SCREEN */
}

/* demo styles */
#header {height: 100px; background: orange}
#content {height: 800px; background: grey}
#footer {height: 150px; background: pink}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="content"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

The difference between HTML and Body has been answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6739791/5325844) StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the body contains everything.

If I understand your question all you should need to do is mess with the `body` in your `.css`

```
body {
    margin: XXXpx
}
```

Replace the X's with a number that best suits what you are after

Comment: What i'm confusing is how to change the position and the size of the body (width,height, margin,padding ... ) in order to make it in the center of display screen. it's working in the left and right of the screen but when it comes to the top and bottom i cant make it exactly in the center of the display screen..

Comment: try this http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: @AmerHamze Can you provide your HTML to give an idea and also proved any `.css` code you currently are using.  This may help